# Prepositional phrase as a pseudo-noun

Tags: prepositions

I’ve been searching about the usage of prepositional phrase as a pseudo-noun, and I’ve found that when it’s used as a subject, the frequency of the usage is like
locational meaning > temporal meaning > the others(so rare).
However, I can’t really see the coherence in other usage, as an object to verbs or prepositions.
The example for PP as a subject is,
“Through the wood” is the nearest way.
and as a objective to verbs is,
I’ll give you “until next morning”.

I think the usage as an object to verbs is just like that as subjects, and that as an object to prepositions is more complicated and collocational problem.
Can you enlighten me...?

Comment: _With a preposition is the right way to begin a prepositional phrase._

Comment: PPs don't act as nouns. What makes you think they can?

Comment: Thank you. Here is the example. “Through the wood” is the nearest way. I’ll give you “until next morning”.

Comment: Neither of them are noun phrases: "through the wood" is a PP functioning as subject, and "until next morning" is a PP functioning as object of"give".